# How can I make my image bigger on Android with XML?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have an image on my `ImageView` but I don't know how to make it bigger **with XML**. My image it's the following:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/image"/>
```

I tried changing `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` attributes but if I put them with a number (for example, `200dp width` and `100dp height`) the `ImageView` it's on the left of the screen and not center.

I want to center the image and makes it a little bit bigger than the original. I couldn't find anything to makes it bigger at the same time it is displayed on the center of the screen.

Is it possible? How can I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What it's wrong on the question?

Comment: Use [ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Comment: Nothing wrong.did you use scaletype with adjustviewbounds ??

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I'm trying all the options that all of you provide to me. I'm still prove them. I want to see their performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both codes above works (`Andrew Brooke` and `IntelliJ Amiya`, Thanks!) but now I found a "trick" to avoid both of these methods. It's to create the `ImageView` using `android:minWidth` and `android:minHeight` so the final `ImageView` will be like:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:minHeight="70dp"
    android:src="@drawable/image"/>
```

With that, you can center your `ImageView` with the size that you want.

Answer (score 2):

Use `scaletype` and add `android:adjustviewbounds="true"` in your image view section.

Comment: If I put, for example, `android:layout_width="100dp"`, `android:layout_height="70dp"`,  `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` and         `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` the image it's like if it were on -50dp position. More than the middle of the image couldn't be seen because it is on the left of the screen. If I quit the option `android:adjustviewbounds="true"` nothing change.

Comment: Add centerinde scaletype

Comment: Did you add layout gravity center??

Comment: Ok now it's show on the center of the screen. With `android:layout_gravity`  but it's like the `ImageView` it's cut (not the full image it's shown).

Comment: Glad to receive that you overcome. Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Keep the size you want as the width and height of the `ImageView` and change the `gravity` of its parent to `center`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT:**

If this is what you want your layout to look like

[image]

then all you would need to do is add

```
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
```

to your `ImageView`, and specify the `width` and `height` in `dp`

Comment: Thanks for answer! But I can't do that because I have on the same `LinearLayout` more than one elements (that I don't want to be centered).

Comment: That's fine, just wrap it in its own `LinearLayout`

Comment: Is it not a bit dirty to add a lot of `LinearLayout`?

Comment: It can be. You always want to try to optimize your layouts well. Could you provide an image of how you want this layout to look, with the rest of your content?

Comment: I will try to do it avoiding the extra `LinearLayout`. I already tried it and I wanted something more clear. But thanks for the answer! It's also a good one.

Comment: No problem. Also take a look at my edited answer, if that's what you want to achieve, you don't need an extra `LinearLayout`

Comment: Now I found a trick to avoid the `LinearLayout`. Do you think should I post it here as an answer?

Comment: Ok then I will post it now.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 attributes you can add to your imageview:

```
android:scaleType=""
android:scaleX=""
android:scaleY=""
```

`ScaleType` types can be seen [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html). Basically, you'll want to use `CENTER_CROP`.

`scaleX` and `scaleY` uses float as parameters, defining the scale for the two axis. See the reference [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:scaleX).

Comment: So scaleType it's for use with a particular dimension, right? Instead of `match_parent` or `wrap_content`.